# Problem with Error in Datasource SSAS Tabular

Tags: ssas-tabular

I am having problem with error when I was trying to load Tables from Database AdventureDW2019 to my new project in SSAS Tabular. The error said "The credentials provided for the SQL source are invalid.

I am using SQL Server 2019 and did select EITHER Window Service Account OR Window Impersonate Account by typing Mycomputername\username in responding the DataSource Wizard but it still gave me error. I have checked my SQL server compability is 1500.

Kindly some advice and really appreciate it.